# Is there an exact algorithm for the minimum makespan scheduling with 2 identical machines and N processes that exists for small constraints?

Tags: algorithm, logic, scheduling, dynamic-programming, greedy

If 2 identical machines are given, with N jobs with i'th job taking T[i] time to complete, is there an exact algorithm to assign these N jobs to the 2 machines so that the makespan is minimum or the total time required to complete all the N jobs is minimum?
I need to solve the problem only for N=50.
Also note that total execution time of all the processes is bounded by 10000.

Does greedily allocating the largest job to the machine which gets free work?

```
// s1 -> machine 1
 //s2->machine 2 , a[i]-> job[i] ,time-> time consumed,jobs sorted in descending order
 // allocated one by one to the machine which is free.
   long long  ans=INT_MAX;
   sort(a,a+n);
   reverse(a,a+n);
   int i=2;
   int s1=a[0];
   int s2=a[1];
   long long time=min(s1,s2);
   s1-=time;
   s2-=time;
   while(i<n)
   {

       if(s1==0 && s2==0)
       {
           s1=a[i];
           if(i+1<n) s2=a[i+1];
           int c=min(s1,s2);
           time+=c;
           s1-=c;
           s2-=c;
           i+=2;
           continue;
       }
       else
       {
           if(s1<s2) swap(s1,s2);
           s2=a[i];

           int c=min(s1,s2);
           time+=c;
           s1-=c;
           s2-=c;
           i++;

       }
   }
   assert(s1*s2==0);
   ans = min(ans,time+max(s1,s2));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you described is *NP*-hard via a more or less straightforward reduction from [Subset Sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which makes an excat polynomial time algorithm impossible unless *P=NP*. Greedy assignment will *not* yield an optimal solution in general. However, as the number of jobs is bounded by 50, any exact algorithm with running time exponential in `N` is in fact an algorithm with constant running time.

The problem can be tackled via dynamic programming as follows. Let `P` be the sum of all processing times, which is an upper bound for the optimal makespan. Define an array `S[N][P]` as state space. The meaning of `S[i][j]` is the minimum makespan attainable for jobs indexed by `1,...,i` where the load of machine 1 is exactly `j`. An outer loop iterates over the jobs, an inner loop over the target load of machine 1. In each iteration, we have do decide whether job `i` should run on machine 1 or machine 2. The determination of the state value of course has to be done in such a way that only solutions which exist are taken into account.

In the first case, we set `S[i][j]` to the minimum of `[i-1][j-T[i]] + T[i]` (the resulting load of machine 1) and the sum of `pi'` for `i'` in `{1,...,i-1}` minus `[i-1][j-T[i]]` (the resulting load of machine 2, so to speak the complementary load of machine 1 which is not changed by our choice).

In the second case, we set `S[i][j]` to the minimum of `[i-1][j]` (the resulting load of machine 1 which is not changed by our choice) and the sum of `T[i']` for `i'` in `{1,...,i-1}` minus `[i-1][j-T[i]]` plus `T[i]` (the resulting load of machine 2, so to speak the complementary load of machine 1).

Finally, the optimal makespan can be found by determining the minimum value of `S[N][j]` for each `j`. Note that the approach only calculates the optimum value, but not an optimal solution itself. An optimal solution can be found by backtracking or using suitable auxiliary data structures. The running time and space requirement would be `O(N*P)`, i.e. pseudopolynomial in `N`.

Note that the problem and the approach are very similar to the [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). However for the scheduling problem, the choice is not to be made whether or not to include an item but whether or not to execute a job on machine 1 or machine 2.

Also note that the problem is actually well-studied; the problem description in so-called three-field notation is `P2||Cmax`. If I recall correctly, however greedily scheduling jobs in non-increasing order of processing time yields an approximation ratio of 2 as proved in the following article.

R.L. Graham, "Bounds-for certain multiprocessing anomalies," Bell System Technological Journal 45 (1966) 1563-1581

Comment: Considering that there are only 2 machines, N=50 ,and total time taken for jobs to complete is bounded by 10000,I am quite sure that a dynamic programming solution using N*Sum(Time[i]) space and time complexity might exist.

Comment: Also, it is mentioned that number of jobs is bounded by 50.

Comment: And so you can think of a DP solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you elaborate as I am not able to formulate it?